# Vue: How to reference item and list context in method receiving child component event

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have several lists using the same child component which passes an event with argument back to the parent. In the event handler in the parent component, is there a way to reference the item and list dynamically? Or does everything need to be explicitly passed to the event handler from the child component? I feel like I'm missing something obvious here.

```
// Parent
<Child
  v-for="(item, index) in apples"
  :item="item"
  :index="index"
  :key="item.id"
  @clicked="eventHandler"
/>

<Child
  v-for="(item, index) in oranges"
  :item="item"
  :index="index"
  :key="item.id"
  @clicked="eventHandler"
/>

methods: {
  eventHandler(val) {
    // 1. How do I access item here?
    // 2. How do I access apples/oranges here? (without explicitly referencing this.apples)
  }
}

// Child
<b-button @click="action('foo')">Click me</b-button>

methods: {
  action(val) {
    this.$emit('clicked', val);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the item in the `change` event handler at the parent component:

```js
const child = Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child',
  props: { item: { type: Object }, index: { type: Number } },
  methods: { action(val) { this.$emit('clicked', val); } }
});

new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  components: { child },
  data: () => ({ apples: [ { id:1, type:'apple' } ], oranges: [ { id:1, type:'orange' } ] }),
  methods: {
    eventHandler(item, childData) {
      // 1. How do I access item here?
      console.log(item)
      console.log(childData)
      // 2. How do I access apples/oranges here?
      //console.log("apples", this.apples);
      //console.log("oranges", this.oranges);
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>

<template id="child">
  <button @click="action('foo')">
    {{ item.type }} {{ item.id }} - Click me
  </button>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <child
      v-for="(item, index) in apples"
      :item="item"
      :index="index"
      :key="item.id"
      @clicked="(...childData) => eventHandler(item, ...childData)"
    />
  </div>
  <div>
    <child
      v-for="(item, index) in oranges"
      :item="item"
      :index="index"
      :key="item.id"
      @clicked="(...childData) => eventHandler(item, ...childData)"
    />
  </div>
</div>
```